# Docker run throwing an error class not found

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, build.gradle

This is probably a duplicate question but I have searched a lot and I couldn't find an answer that worked. I am sure that I am making a simple mistake but I just can't figure it out.

I have created a simple core Java project using `Gradle wrapper 7.6`.

I was able to create a docker image using `docker build` command but when I ran the command, I got the following error:

```
Could not find or load main class io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication
```

Here is the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM gradle:7.6.1-jdk8 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY build.gradle ./
RUN gradle build --scan --stacktrace 
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-jre
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/*.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-0.0.1-plain.jar"]
```

Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0"
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id "maven-publish"
        id "java"
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    }
    
    //sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    //targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    version = "0.0.1"
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
        }
    }
    
    apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
    //apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    
    dependencies {
        implementation "io.confluent.parallelconsumer:parallel-consumer-core:0.5.2.4"
        implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1"
        implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:3.3.0"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
        implementation "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13"
        implementation "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
        implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0"
        implementation "me.tongfei:progressbar:0.9.3"
        implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
        implementation("log4j:log4j:1.2.17")
    
        testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
        testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
        testImplementation "io.confluent.parallelconsumer:parallel-consumer-core:0.5.2.4:tests" // for LongPollingMockConsumer
    }
    
    test {
        testLogging {
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
            showStandardStreams = true
            exceptionFormat = "full"
        }
    }
    
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
    
    
    jar {
      manifest {
        attributes(
          "Class-Path": configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(" "),
          'Main-Class': 'io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication',
        )
      }
    }
    
    
    shadowJar {
        archiveBaseName = "confluent-parallel-consumer-application-standalone"
    }
```

This is not a spring boot application, I just used the `RestTemplate` in the project to make an API call.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ParallelConsumerApplication is not something provided by any of the dependencies, it is a class you yourself need to write, see https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/confluent-parallel-consumer/confluent.html

So clearly the error is caused because you didn't create such a class in your application. If you created it with another name, you need to use the name of your main application class instead of io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication

Comment: `ParallelConsumerApplication` is the name of my java class which contains the main function.

Comment: Not just the name of the class matters, you probably put it in a different package. You would need to show the code for this class at least. It should start with:

package io.confluent.developer;

And be in a a folder src/main/io/confluent/developer/

Comment: yes it's inside package `src/main/io/confluent/developer/` only.

Comment: But does it contain the "package io.confluent.developer;" statement in the source file? Could you paste this source file?